# Can anyone solve 'int' object is not callable? I am having problem with maths question

Tags: python, math, integer

```
def f(x):
    answer = (x**3)-3(x**2)-5(x)-7 
    return answer
print(f(-1))
print(f(0))
print(f(1))
print(f(2))
print(f(3))
print(f(4))
print(f(5))
```

Comment: `3(x**2)` should be `3 * (x**2)`. The same applies to `5(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

Provide a `*` for multiplication

```
answer = (x**3)-3*(x**2)-5*(x)-7 
return answer
```